# TransactionScope operation could not be performed because server was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: c#, wpf, transactionscope

I have a situation that i encountered this error:

1. Have multiple Database(Server (DB1 and DB2))
2. After a transaction in application using Transactionscope (in DB1) (completed before the end of Using statement), then i insert into another table (TB1 in DB1) a record (this table has trigger insert into DB2), then hit this error. Wherever i use a TransactionScope in DB1 and then call the insertion script to TB1 which has this trigger, it will always have this error
3. However, after i calling other update functions that do not have a TransactionScope in DB1, and then insert into TB1, it is then ok to insert.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: using trans.Complete()

Comment: Trying adding trans.Dispose() after Complete(), still cannot work

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Are you trying to generate two transaction scopes?  Would be helpful to see a small extract of the problematic code.